# How to get next empty cell position in a specific column, Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im building a apps script to process existing data in a spreadsheet, and build new columns of data based on the existing data. How do I find the next empty cell(not the last cell) in any given column?

Here is the code I initially wrote.

```
function isempty(x, y){
  alert(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(y, x).isBlank());
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(y, x).isBlank();
}
function nextopencell(column){
  var x = 0;
  var b = 1;
  while(b != 2){
   x++;
   var data = isempty(x, column);
    if(data == true){
      b = 2;
    }
  }
  alert(x);
return x;
}
```

When there is 5 non empty cells in a column, the first of these being first cell in the column, I expect the return value to be 6, but the function returns 3 regardless of the actual states(not-empty, empty) of cells in a column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why getRange(**y,x**)?

Comment: Read best practices in [tag:google-apps-script] info page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) expects the row first and the column second, so flip the `x` & `y` in your `getRange()` calls.

```
function isempty(x, y) {
  alert(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x, y).isBlank());
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x, y).isBlank();
}
```

Also, please read the Apps Script [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) and consider ways to improve your script. For example, in the snippet above, you're executing `isBlank()` twice, but you only need to do so once.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Yes i know i was only doing that in an attempt to debug my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach for what you are intending to do. In my code, I'm using the [`.getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) method. This will get all data in your sheet and then with the for-loop, you can iterate over all rows and specify with your ***column*** argument, from what column you want the values.

```
function nextopencell(column){

  // Get the active spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // This represents ALL the data
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // Build a new array to fill it with the desire data
  var newColArray = [];

  // Iterate over all rows
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    // With the column we specify in what column we want to extract the data
    if (values[i][column]) {
       // fill array
       newColArray.push(values[i][column]);
    } else{
       // Show what cells are empty
       Logger.log("This is an empty cell at column " + (column+1).toString() + " and row " + (i+1).toString());
    }
  }

  // This is the built array to fill a new column as you want
  Logger.log(newColArray);

}
```

For more info, you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).

Comment: Thank you. I have been reading about using arrays in Apps Script and your example definitely solidifies what i have been reading.

Comment: Be careful with `.getDataRange()` as it will only return the "visible" data. Columns/rows that are hidden/filtered out will not be returned.